# Pass Structure by reference as argument in JNA

Tags: java, dll, structure, pass-by-reference, jna

I have a dynamic link library (DLL) written in c++. In my DLL I have a function like this:

```cpp
void anpr_set_params(byte instance, SLPRParams* params);
```

Where `SLPRParams` is a Structure containing byte, int, float and array of them.

Now, I want to use my DLL in Java. I'm using JNA to call native code in my java project. I tried get help from [this site](https://www.baeldung.com/java-object-memory-address) to get the address of my structure in java and pass it to my dll, and I defined my signature function in Java like this:

```java
void anpr_set_params(byte instance, long slpr_params);
```

But the address i get in c++ is different from the address i sent in Java.

Then I looked for another solution and read the this [JNA FAQ entry](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#when-should-i-use-structurebyreference-structurebyvalue-structure).

I tested all types but every time I get a runtime error.

Comment: if you're trying to apply "pass by reference" using java, please read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: It is very nice to know that your "SLPRParams is a Structure contains byte, int, float and array of them" but I am afraid you are going to need to show us the exact definition of that "structure" as you call it.  Both the Java definition and the C++ definition. Might be a good idea to strip the structure down to only one or two members and get that to work first, and you can add more members later.

Comment: In first solution i have problem in difference address of my structure between c++ and java and in second solution i have run time error, then it seems its not important what is in my structure exactly. but i tried the order of the elements be the same in c++ and java

Comment: @Stultuske good advice in general, but this concerns the specific peculiarities of passing Structure classes in JNA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the `Structure` directly as an argument.

As explained in [JNA Structures and Unions](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/StructuresAndUnions.md#using-structures-and-unions),

> When a function requires a pointer to a struct, a Java Structure should be used.

Also, the [javadoc for `Structure`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.11.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html) says:

> When used as a function parameter or return value, this class corresponds to `struct*`. When used as a field within another `Structure`, it corresponds to `struct`. The tagging interfaces `Structure.ByReference` and `Structure.ByValue` may be used to alter the default behavior.

Passing a pointer to a structure like `SLPRParams* params` is the most common way that DLLs expect structures, and that `ByReference` type is the default behavior.  Only if the full structure is passed inline would you need to use the `ByValue` tag on it.

A nested Structure inside another Structure works the opposite way; it is `ByValue` by default and would need the `ByReference` tag if it was declared as a pointer.

The [examples in the JNA FAQ](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#when-should-i-use-structurebyreference-structurebyvalue-structure) (which you also linked) may make more sense once you understand this distinction.  The relevant example is this one:

```c
void myfunc(simplestruct* data); // use Structure
```

In your case the correct mapping is

```java
void anpr_set_params(byte instance, SLPRParams slpr_params);
```

The mapping with `long` might appear to work on 64-bit non-Windows operating systems if you extracted the structure's pointer's peer value (`Pointer.nativeValue(params.getPointer()`). But it wouldn't be portable.  Just pass the Structure and JNA handles the rest.